# What is fundamentally wrong with my approach?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, proof-verification

I've got a couple of these sort of questions wrong, and its pretty demoralising. Is it the method I'm using, or is it just arithmetic/silly errors? Here's one:

> Use trigonometric identities before using a substitution (or reversing the chain rule) to integrate the following.
>
> part c) $\int \sin\left(x\right)\cos\left(x\right)e^{\cos2x}$

Sub $u=\cos(x)$

$\int \sin\left(x\right)ue^{\cos\left(2x\right)}dx=\int \sin\left(x\right)ue^{2u^2-1}dx\:$

$=-1\int ue^{2u^2-1}du\:$

Then integration by parts:

$\frac{u}{2}e^{2u-1}-\int \:\frac{1}{2}e^{2u^2-1}=\frac{u}{2}e^{2u-1}-\frac{1}{4}e^{2u^2-1}$

$=\frac{\cos\left(x\right)}{2}e^{2\cos^2x-1}-\frac{1}{4}e^{2\cos^2x-1}$

$-1\cdot \frac{\cos\left(x\right)}{2}e^{2\cos^2x-1}-\frac{1}{4}e^{2\cos^2x-1}=\frac{-\cos\left(x\right)}{2}e^{2\cos^2x-1}+\frac{1}{4}e^{2\cos^2x-1}$

Comment: The simpler way is $\sin x \cos x = \sin 2x / 2$ (literally _before using a substitution_...).

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that. I just tried it and got the right answer that way (thanks!). I wonder what was wrong with my more long winded approach, though.

Comment: Where you write

$\int \sin\left(x\right)ue^{2u^2-1}dx\ = -1\int ue^{2u-1}du$

Have you accidentally dropped $u^2$ in the exponent to $u$?

Comment: Sorry, that was just my poor transferral of working!

Comment: The question states "use trigonometric identities before using a substitution" and the first thing you did was use a substitution!

Comment: Your integration by parts is indeed wrong, as promised :). Write out $f$ and $g$ in $\int f'(u) g(u) du$, you'll see the problem.